# Is there a way to bypass google's 100 search quota?

Tags: c#, .net, google-search-api

Google has a 100 search quota, which is way too low to be of any use. Every time I run a search, the quota increases by 1. Here's the code:

```
string apiKey = "(MY API KEY HERE)";
string cx = "(MY CUSTOM SEARCH ENGINE CODE HERE)";
var tempi = 0;

var svc = new Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CustomsearchService(new BaseClientService.Initializer { ApiKey = apiKey });

string query = "test"
potato = 0;
var listRequest = svc.Cse.List(query);
listRequest.Cx = cx;
var search = listRequest.Execute();

foreach (var result in search.Items.Take(3))
{
    if (potato == 0)
    {
         console.WriteLine("**Title:** " + result.Title + "\n**Link:** " + result.Link);
         potato += 1;
    }
}
```

Is there any way of using this without having to use up the query every time? If not, is there any other API that can do something similar to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of Google's commercial model. If you want to exceed the quota, then you need to start paying for the service.

[You can find the pricing here.](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/72334?hl=en)